# jQuery validation and retrieving values in one ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In our web application, we want to process the value of a certain text box using an ajax call as soon as a certain button is clicked:

```
$("#the-button").click(function() {
    if ($("#the-form").validate().element($("the-button"))) {
        var oldValue = $("#the-button").value(),
            newValue = process(oldValue);
    }
});
```

The `process()` method hides a `synchronous` ajax call to retrieve some value based on the text in the text box.

Before doing the process() though, we validate the field with a custom adapter which uses the same ajax call just to see whether or not the server is able to process the value. (This is for a reason.)

Now we would like to optimize this: Basically the entry is valid *if and only if it can be processed*:

```
$.validator.addMethod("canBeProcessed", function(value, element) {
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        ...,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            result = true;
            // the actual result is ignored
        }
        error: function () {
            result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}, "Value cannot be processed");
```

So it would be nice if we could validate *and* process the value in one go:

```
$.validator.addMethod("canBeProcessed", function(value, element) {
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        ...,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            result = true;
            saveForLaterUse(data); // <-- save the result
        }
        error: function () {
            result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}, "Value cannot be processed");
```

How do you suggest to solve this problem? We don't want to store the value in any hard-coded global variable. It should be retrievable from the textbox so the validation rule could be applied even if the result value will not be needed.